# PayPal sandbox takes me to live site when trying to change Payment Solution to Website Payments Standard

Tags: paypal

When I am trying to change the payment solution from from 'PayPal Digital Goods (PayPal Express Checkout)' to 'Website payments Standard' in the sandbox, I get redirected to the live paypal site.

I have seen a similar question asked here which was resolved by adding the payment solution to the account by a paypal developer team member.

Any idea on how I can add the desired payment solution added?

Thanks in advance

Jami

Comment: Please share what kind of project this is in. Is is part of a particular e-commerce engine or CMS? Are you writing something from scratch?

Comment: Can you please post some example code? If your endpoints are pointing to the live site this can happen, so viewing the code can help us diagnose the issue.

Comment: Hi there, It appears that when I logged into Paypal the next day, it defaulted to 'Website payments Standard' so I can't replicate the issue. Thanks heaps for your help though.